# MySQL UNION duplicating results

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve data from two tables, 'publisher' and 'magazine'. I'm listing the publishers, and want to show, in the "magazines" column, the count of the magazines rows. I'm using this code:

```
(
SELECT 
    p.id as id,
    p.publisher as publisher, 
    p.flag as flag,
    p.visits as visits, 
    IF(p.magazines>0,COUNT(distinct m.id),0) AS magazines 
FROM publisher p, magazine m
WHERE m.publisher = p.id
GROUP BY p.publisher
)
UNION
(
SELECT
        p.id as id,
        p.publisher as publisher, 
        p.flag as flag, 
        p.visits as visits, 
        p.magazines as magazines
FROM publisher p
GROUP BY p.publisher
)
ORDER BY publisher
```

But what I obtain as result is something like this:

```
ID  Pub     Magazines           Visits 
7   Pub7    1                   2
7    Pub7    15                  2
5   Pub5    0                   4
4   Pub4    0                   3
3   Pub3    2                   26
2   Pub2    2                   13
1   Pub1    9                   18
6   Pub6    1                   1
```

As you see, the last record shows twice and has somehow the aggregate of the magazines. I don't know what is wrong in the SQL syntax, could somehow please help me solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about [GROUP BY hidden columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html). To avoid problems, copy all listed SELECT clause fields into GROUP BY, all except aggregate fields.

```
SELECT 
    p.id as id,
    p.publisher as publisher, 
    p.flag as flag,
    sum( p.visits ) as visits,
    COUNT(distinct m.id) AS magazines 
FROM 
   publisher p left outer join 
   magazine m
     on m.publisher = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.publisher, p.flag
ORDER BY publisher
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Actually, the LEFT OUTER JOIN solved it, I didn't realize It was that simple. Thank you.